# Builder pattern in place of method overloading

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, coding-style, builder-pattern

I have an interface TaxCalculator that looks like this

public interface TaxCalculator {
    int DEFAULT_AMOUNT_FOR_RATE_CALCULATION = 100;

```
/**
 *
 * @param cart the cart to calculate taxes for. Right now we are only calculating using the total taxable amount, but when we implement
 *             charging taxes properly, we should use data from the cart like line-item amounts, and types.
 * @return the tax rate to charge for this cart
 */
SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(ShoppingCart cart, Address address);
SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(ShoppingCart cart, String zipcode);

SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(Order order) throws Exception;



/** Since taxes ideally get calculated using information like line-item amounts, and types, you cannot get an accurate
 * rate from the taxable amount alone. This is a function we want to support, however, on pages such as calculate payboo savings.
 *
 * @param taxableAmount the amount to calculate taxes for
 * @return a quote for what taxes will likely come out to
 */
SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(double taxableAmount, String zipCode);

SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(String zipCode);

SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(Address address);

SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(double taxableAmount, Address address);

default SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(double taxableAmount, ZipCode zipCode){
    return getSalesTaxes(taxableAmount,zipCode.getZipCode());
}
default SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes( ZipCode zipCode){
    return getSalesTaxes(zipCode.getZipCode());
}
default SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(ShoppingCart cart, ZipCode zipcode){
    return getSalesTaxes(cart,zipcode.getZipCode());
}
```

I have two implementations that calculate tax, one going to an api, and one internal system
I have a third implementation that acts as a proxy - effectively on each call it works like this

```
@Override
    public SalesTaxRates getSalesTaxes(ShoppingCart cart, Address address)
    {
        Map<String,SalesTaxRates> cache = getTaxSessionCache();
        String cacheKey = generateCacheKey(cart,address);
        if(cache.containsKey(cacheKey))
            return cache.get(cacheKey);
        TaxCallable taxCallable = new TaxCallable() {
            @Override
            public SalesTaxRates call() {
                return this.getTaxCalculator().getSalesTaxes(cart,address);
            }
        };
        SalesTaxRates taxRates = callTaxCalculators(taxCallable);
        if(taxRates.isCacheable())
            cache.put(cacheKey, taxRates);
        return taxRates;
    }
```

And the method defined:

```
private static SalesTaxRates callTaxCalculators(TaxCallable callable)
    {
        for (TaxCalculator taxCalculator: TaxEngine.getTaxCalculators())
        {
            FutureTask<SalesTaxRates> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable.setTaxCalculator(taxCalculator));
            new Thread(futureTask).start();
            try {
                SalesTaxRates taxRates = futureTask.get(getTaxCalculatorTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(taxRates!=null && taxRates.isCalculated())
                {
                    BHLogger.info("Used taxcalculator: " + taxRates.getTaxEngine() + "rate: " + taxRates.getTotalTaxRate());
                    return taxRates;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                BHLogger.error(e);
            }
        }
        BHLogger.error("ShoppingCart.calculteSalesTax","No taxCalculator calculated taxes correctly");
        return SalesTaxRates.NOT_CALCULATED;
    }
```

it checks the cache, sees if its there, and returns it. Otherwise it calls the forwarding message and caches it
So this seems very repetitive for each overloaded method, but there isnt an obvious way for me to call one method since the cacheing is different
My manager suggested I used the builder pattern. Make a TaxRequest object, which has whatever relevant fields. It could take care of its own cacheing

I guess it would look like this

```
class TaxRequest{
private Order order;
private Cart cart;
private Address address;
private String zipcode;
private SalesTaxRates send(TaxCalculator tc){
   //check cache
   //else
   tc.getSalesTaxes(this);
   //handlecaching
}
}
```

The interface only needs one method, and the Forwarding class becomes very simple
I guess the ApiTaxCalculator implementation now needs to handle this by having a method like this

```
SalesTaxRates getSalesTax(TaxRequest taxRequest)
{
   if(taxRequest.hasOrder()
       returnGetSalesTaxes(taxRequest.getOrder);
  //if has address and cart... if has only address... if has just a zip...
}
```

basically, the suggestion is to use the builder pattern instead of method overloading
but that last method seems very awkward to me,
Another reason why this was suggested, the internal taxCalculator doesnt do anything different with an Order than it does just a zipcode. Ideally it should take things like itemtype into account, or discounts etc. but it doesnt. It just looks up a rate based on zipcode
so theres a lot of overhead in that class just forwarding it to that method

Any advice?

Comment: Not sure I can follow you (that's quite the large text), but your base interface could only have a `String` and `WithZipCode` overload whereas `WithZipCode` is an interface that would be implemented by `ZipCode`, `Order` etc. that just provides the getter `String getZipCode()`. Your callables then only needs to accept and cache objects of the type `WithZipCode`. And as `WithZipCode` has only one function passing a raw `String` could be done with a `() -> zipCodeString`. If something is unclear give me a heads up and I'll provide sample code

Comment: You could leave caching to `TaxCalculator` and build cache key based on `TaxRequest`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. These methods are very different. The more information you give the better. For example, give an order, and I can see which items are taxable, what discounts you have, your shipping charges etc.
I'm not just drilling down to the zipcode
That IS what happens with one of the implementations. But the clients should NOT know that

Comment: Is this for a library? I want sense should they not know? They could inspect the code

Comment: Knowing in the sense of they dont have to handle calling the right function?

Comment: Meaning that that should be encapsulated. As far as you know, these are the methods offered. You do not need to know how this class is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

class StackOverflowQuestion56893388Scratch {
    static class SalesTaxRates {
        //TODO: don't know anything about it
    }

    interface WithZipCode {
        String getZipCode();
    }

    interface WithShipping {
        Optional<Integer> getShippingCosts();
    }

    interface WithDiscount {
        Optional<Integer> getDiscount();
    }

    static class ZipCode implements WithZipCode {
        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public String getZipCode() { return null; }
    }

    //I chose arbitrary interfaces here as I don't know more about your domain
    static class ShoppingCart implements WithZipCode, WithShipping {
        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public String getZipCode() { return null; }

        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> getShippingCosts() { return Optional.empty(); }
    }

    //I chose arbitrary interfaces here as I don't know more about your domain
    static class Order implements WithZipCode, WithShipping, WithDiscount {
        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public String getZipCode() { return null; }

        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> getShippingCosts() { return Optional.empty(); }

        /*TODO: return some field*/
        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> getDiscount() { return Optional.empty(); }
    }

/////////////////////////////////TAXCALCULATOR///////////////////////////////////////////

    static class TaxCalculator {
        public SalesTaxRates getSaleTaxes(String zipCode) {
            return getSaleTaxes(() -> zipCode);
        }

        public SalesTaxRates getSaleTaxes(WithZipCode zipCode) {
            return getSaleTaxesInternal((AllTaxRelatedInformation) zipCode::getZipCode);
        }

        public SalesTaxRates getSaleTaxes(ShoppingCart cart) {
            return getSaleTaxesInternal(new AllTaxRelatedInformation() {
                @Override
                public String getZipCode() { return cart.getZipCode(); }

                @Override
                public Optional<Integer> getShippingCosts() { return cart.getShippingCosts(); }
            });
        }

        public SalesTaxRates getSaleTaxes(Order order) {
            return getSaleTaxesInternal(order);
        }

        private Map<CacheKey, SalesTaxRates> cache = new HashMap<>();
        private <T extends WithZipCode & WithShipping & WithDiscount> SalesTaxRates getSaleTaxesInternal(T input) {
            SalesTaxRates cachedValue = cache.get(new CacheKey(input, input, input));
            if(cachedValue != null) {
                return cachedValue;
            }

            //TODO: calculation here
            return null;
        }

        private interface AllTaxRelatedInformation extends WithZipCode, WithShipping, WithDiscount {
            @Override
            default Optional<Integer> getShippingCosts() { return Optional.empty(); }
            @Override
            default Optional<Integer> getDiscount() { return Optional.empty(); }
        }

        private class CacheKey {
            private final WithZipCode zipCode;
            private final WithShipping shipping;
            private final WithDiscount discount;

            private CacheKey(WithZipCode zipCode, WithShipping shipping, WithDiscount discount) {
                this.zipCode = zipCode;
                this.shipping = shipping;
                this.discount = discount;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                //TODO: implement equals by shipping cost, delivery and zipCode
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                //TODO: implement hashCode by shipping cost, delivery and zipCode
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(The above code compiles standalone, drop all `static` prefixes on the classes when you refactor it into your codebase).

This was quite the big question but as I understood it (after discussing in the comments) you wanted and extendable way to handle including multiple sometimes optional values into your calculation. The above code funnels all different variations into a single calculation function that has to handle the presence or absence of some values (I marked those `Optional`). You only have to implement the calculation logic once now and have a way better cache key. I omitted the implementation for `ZipCode`, `Order` and `ShoppingCart` to shorten the code (should be easy with a field of some sort).

I hope I understood you correctly, feel free to comment on any misunderstandings or if anything is unclear.